# Linking users in wiki pages

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

We have a Wiki added to an Azure DevOps project.  And when trying to link a project member in a Wiki page, I'm only able to list one of the members when adding a @ to the page.  None of the other members are listed.  I have verified that the other members have access to the page.  Is there anything else I need to do to be able to link the other members?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm only able to list one of the members when adding a @ to the page.

This is as designed. The others who could not be appeared in the drop list does not mean that they has any issue on this org. Just when you print `@`, it only list those people that you've recently mentioned. We called it `memory`.

[image]

> Is there anything else I need to do to be able to link the other
>   members?

You need continue to print the member's name, don't need the completed spell, just type part of name and **press Enter**. At this time, the server will start **fuzzy search** to list the similar users for you choose. In one word, the user search will appear similar to when you start typing a user name into the assigned To field.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I did try writing additional characters in the input box.  But it seems fuzzy search is not enabled until I actually click on "Search" under the input box.  At that point it fuzzy searches whatever I write in the input box.

Comment: @Oystein, apologize, I lost the key action : **press enter**. Don't need click on search, just press enter is ok. Will updated this key action on my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  But why the Enter keypress, if you don't mind me asking?  Wouldn't it be more intuitive to start fuzzy searching immediately when the user starts typing something?

Comment: @Oystein, For wiki content, it does not include one automatic process which identify the symbol `@`. Press enter from keyboard or click on search, these are all calling the process to start fuzzy search. The automatically search without any other action only applied on WIT and PR comment.